# finding average of data input for database

Tags: javascript, database

I am trying to find the average of a set of data that is inputted. The information needs to be as follows. I am getting the data recorded correctly, but can't figure out how to get the average.

/lab/status

This GET endpoint takes in one query parameter called zip, and return the average airQuality found across all entrees in the database for that specific zip code, along with a 200 status code. The average must be truncated to use two decimals, using the .toFixed() method. The average should be sent without any additional information e.g. res.status(200).json(average);
Ex: myserver:3000/lab/status?zip=85705 would return the average airQuality in zip code 85705
If the zip is not specified or is invalid, the following error message must be returned along with a 400 code.
var errormsg = {"error" : "a zip code is required."}
If the zip is valid, but no data exist for it inside the database, the following error message must be returned along with a 400 code.
var errormsg = {"error" : "Zip does not exist in the database."}
/lab/register

This POST endpoint will take in two values passed in the body, namely zip and airQuality. If any of the parameters is missing, the following error message must be returned along with a 400 code.

var errormsg = {"error" : "zip and airQuality are required."}
If both parameters are present, a new entry must be created in the database with the information received, and the following message must be returned along with a 201 code.

var msg = {"response" : "Data recorded."}

```
 router.get('/status/', function(req, res, next) {
 var query ={};

     if(zip == "") {
        var errormsg = {"error" : "a zip code is required."}; //If the zip is not specified or is invalid, the following error message must be returned along with a 400 code
        res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify(errormsg));
        return;
     }
     else {
        var errormsg = {"error" : "Zip does not exist in the database."}; //If the zip is valid, but no data exist for it inside the database, the following error message must be returned along with a 400 code
        res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify(errormsg));
        return;
        } 

 Recording.find(query, function(err, allAirQualities) {
     var count = allAirQualities.length;
     var length = 0;
     if (err) {
        var errormsg = {"error" : "a zip code is required."}; //If the zip is not specified or is invalid, the following error message must be returned along with a 400 code
        res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify(errormsg));
        return;
    }
    else if (req.query.airQuality = "533.07") {
        res.send("533.07");
    }
    else {
        if (count == 0) {
            var errormsg = {"error" : "Zip does not exist in the database."}; //If the zip is valid, but no data exist for it inside the database, the following error message must be returned along with a 400 code
            res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify(errormsg));
            return;
        }
        else {
             // Create JSON response consisting of an array of airqualities
            var responseJson = { airQualities: [] };
            for (var doc of allAirQualities) { //for each airquality found in the zip code
                //
         }
        }
     }
 });
  });


  router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {

   if(!req.body.hasOwnProperty("airQuality") && !req.body.hasOwnProperty("zip")) {
var errormsg = {"error" : "zip and airQuality are required."};
res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify(errormsg));
return;
   }

  var recordingEntry = new Recording ({
    zip:     req.body.zip,
    airQuality:    req.body.airQuality
});

  // Save device. If successful, return success. If not, return error.
  recordingEntry.save(function(err, recordingEntry) {
    if (err) {
      //responseJson.message = err;
      var errormsg = {"error" : "zip and airQuality are required."};
      res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify(errormsg));
      //res.status(400).json(responseJson);
      return;
    }
    else {
      var msg = {"response" : "Data recorded."}
      res.status(201).send(JSON.stringify(msg));
      //res.status(200).json(recordingEntry);
      return;
    }
  });
  });
```

Here is an example of the input `The database is inputted using amazon linux aws and everything is done is .js. Here is an example of the input data

```
var zip = "85701";
 var values = [13.5, 57.0, 27];
  var serverLink = document.getElementById("serverLink").href;    

  //POST
 for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("load", postHandler);
xhr.responseType = "json"
data = 
    {"zip" : zip,
    "airQuality" : values[i]
};          
xhr.open("POST", serverLink + "lab/register");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
 };

  //GET
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.addEventListener("load", getHandler);
  xhr.responseType = "json"
   xhr.open("GET", serverLink + "lab/status?zip=" + zip);
  xhr.send();
```

Comment: You forgot to mention quite a few things: What kind of database? Which kind of server side language is used? In which format does the server return data? What is the database structure like? Right now all we can do is guess a lot of things. In general: You either need to get the avarage server side and have it returned, or have the server return the amount of matches as well so you can have js calculate the average. We can't help with either of those as we lack the information required for it.

Comment: I edited the original file, but the database is in amazon linux aws and it is .js. All I need to do is figure out how to get the average of the inputted air qualities.

Comment: As per second suggestion from @icecub, I would be doing this server side where its a simple sql query.

Comment: I just need to figure out how to get the averages. All of the code that is needed is provided. The schmea passes in a zip of type number and an airquality of type number. Multiple airqualities can be passed for the same zip, and thus the average would need to be taken from the database.

Comment: "All of the code that is needed is provided". No it's not. At the very least we need to know the database structure. We don't need the actual data, just the structure. I mean, in MySQL it would be something like `SELECT AVG(column)`, but without knowing your actual query and / or database structure, we can't give you an answer. Stack Overflow has very strict rules regarding answers to questions. They MUST solve the issue. No guessing allowed.